# Ruby mongo driver: Catch MongoDB connection errors after a few seconds?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am performing this query with my Ruby `mongo` driver:

```rb
begin
  User.collection.find({}).count()
rescue => e
  Rails.logger.error e.to_s
end
```

I would like to catch all situations where this operation fails. The main reason it would fail is if the server was unavailable.

For example, one of the errors I see occasionally is:

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable (No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x70302744731080 tag_sets=[] max_staleness=nil> using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015)
```

I want to catch errors after just 6 seconds.

From [the docs](https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Client.html) I see that there are a few different timeout options (`connect_timeout`, `server_selection_timeout`, `socket_timeout`). But I am not sure which to pass, and how to pass them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. `server_selection_timeout` is the correct option in this case -- it tells the driver how long to wait to find a suitable server before timing out. You can set that option on a new client in the Mongoid configuration file (`config/mongoid.yml`).

You want your configuration file to look something like this:

```
development: # (or production or whatever environment you're using)
  clients:
    default:
      # your default client here
    new_client: # the name of your new client with different options
      database: mongoid
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        server_selection_timeout: 6
        ...
```

Read the [Mongoid Configuration documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#configuration-options) to learn more about setting up config files.

Then, you want to use the new client you defined to perform your query, and rescue any `Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable` errors.

```
begin
  User.with(client: 'new_client').collection.find({}).count()
rescue Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable => e
  # perform error handling here
end
```

Note that this starts up a new `Mongo::Client` instance, which is an expensive operation if done repeatedly. I would recommend that you close the extra client once you are done using it, like so:

```
Mongoid::Clients.with_name('new_client').close
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @egiurleo. Your answer is very useful, and should be left for others who will find this post. But I am specifically interested in setting/overriding the timeout during my request. If possible, could you expand the answer by commenting on how to pass the `server_selection_timeout ` key as parameter in the query?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @JohnSmith1976! I updated my response to reflect your actual question. Let me know if that's helpful!